# fetch a string in file & get all lines containing the string along with line numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Also is it  the correct code which works to fetch  a string in file & get all lines containing the string along with line numbers
am getting syntax error in line 1 for the code,

```
def matched_lines('sam.txt', string_to_search):
    matched_lines = search_string_in_file('sam.txt','is')
    """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
    along with line numbers"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    # Open the file in read only mode 
       with open('sam.txt', 'r') as matched_lines:
           print('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
            # Read all lines in the file one by one
       for elem in matched_lines:
           print('Line Number = ', elem[0], ' :: Line = ', elem[1])
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this result needed?

```
def matched_lines(filename, string_to_search):
    list_of_results = []
    with open(filename, encoding='utf8')as matched_lines:
        for elem in enumerate(matched_lines.read().split('\n')):
            if string_to_search in elem[1]:
                list_of_results.append(elem)
    return list_of_results

result = matched_lines('some.txt', 'lorem')
print('Total Matched lines :', len(result))
print(result)
```